# Repeat array inside array through while loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, array

I want to repeat this array:

```
array(
    'taxonomy' => $tax,
    'field'    => 'slug', 
    'terms'    => $cat,
)
```

because I am getting the value of taxonomy and categories from custom sub field

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'watches',  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => $tax,
        'field'    => 'slug', 
        'terms'    => $cat,
        ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' =>  $taxonomy_2,
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $cat_2,
        ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' =>  $taxonomy_3,
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $cat_3,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating the arguments, but leaving `tax_query` empty:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'watches',
    'tax_query' => array(),
);
```

Then in your loop you can add to `tax_query`with `$args['tax_query'][] =`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'watches',
    'tax_query' => array(),
);

foreach ( $things as $thing ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $thing['taxonomy'],
        'field'    => 'slug', 
        'terms'    => $thing['term'],
    );
}
```

Exactly what you're looping over will likely affect what `$things` is and how you'd use it, but you didn't include that information in your question so I can't help beyond what I've already put.